# docker nuts connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker, nest, nats.io

I am trying to run the second server with 5 docker servises builded with docker compose tool.And i am use another ports for that purpose.Main server is fine,but the second meets the error witn NUTS service.
I have compose yaml config

```
version: "1"
    
    services:
      api-gateway:
        build: ./api-gateway
        restart: always
        hostname: gateway
        env_file:
          - ./api-gateway/env/dev.env
        ports:
          - "8801:8801"
        networks:
          - lazar-network-dev-5
    
      nats:
        image: nats-streaming:0.17.0
        ports:
          - "4223:4223"
        command: ["--port", "4223"]
        networks:
          - lazar-network-dev-5
    
    
    volumes:
      cache:
        driver: local
    
    networks:
      lazar-network-dev-5:
        name: lazar-network-dev-5
        driver: bridge
        attachable: true
```

After running it with **compose up** ,all containers starts up.

NATS give the following information:

```
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.399103 [INF] STREAM: Starting nats-streaming-server[test-cluster] version 0.17.0
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.399183 [INF] STREAM: ServerID: qM6kdWT3QBmVWutzKBt4Lj
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.399187 [INF] STREAM: Go version: go1.13.7
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.399189 [INF] STREAM: Git commit: [f4b7190]
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.401833 [INF] Starting nats-server version 2.1.4
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.401859 [INF] Git commit [fb009af]
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.402773 [INF] Listening for client connections on 0.0.0.0:4223
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.402791 [INF] Server id is NAIUYNZWKVEUHSGSKQ7PJKHMISK6E6UURECTY364J6MDLIKPIBCC4DFA
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.402793 [INF] Server is ready
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.441540 [INF] STREAM: Recovering the state...
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.441572 [INF] STREAM: No recovered state
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692663 [INF] STREAM: Message store is MEMORY
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692764 [INF] STREAM: ---------- Store Limits ----------
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692771 [INF] STREAM: Channels:                  100 *
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692773 [INF] STREAM: --------- Channels Limits --------
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692775 [INF] STREAM:   Subscriptions:          1000 *
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692777 [INF] STREAM:   Messages     :       1000000 *
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692779 [INF] STREAM:   Bytes        :     976.56 MB *
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692781 [INF] STREAM:   Age          :     unlimited *
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692783 [INF] STREAM:   Inactivity   :     unlimited *
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692786 [INF] STREAM: ----------------------------------
api5devtrapezaru-nats-1            | [1] 2024/02/20 07:34:10.692788 [INF] STREAM: Streaming Server is ready
```

Its seems to be ok,but when i try get query for the server **NATS** messaging about an error:

[Nest] 29  - 02/20/2024, 7:39:48 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
api5devtrapezaru-api-gateway-1     | NatsError: CONNECTION_REFUSED
api5devtrapezaru-api-gateway-1     |     at Function.errorForCode (/app/node_modules/nats/nats-base-client/core.ts:168:12)
api5devtrapezaru-api-gateway-1     |     at NodeTransport.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/nats/src/node_transport.ts:94:21)
api5devtrapezaru-api-gateway-1     |     at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
api5devtrapezaru-api-gateway-1     |     at rejected (/app/node_modules/nats/lib/src/node_transport.js:6:65)
api5devtrapezaru-api-gateway-1     |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Calling NUTS from api-gateway

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Lazar API')
    .setDescription('There will be description soon')
    .setVersion('2.0')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.NATS,
    options: {
      servers: ['nats://nats:4223'],
    },
  });

  await app.startAllMicroservices().catch((e) => console.log(e));
  await app.listen(8801, () => {
    console.log('Api-Gateway listening...');
  });
}
bootstrap().catch((err: Error) => {
  console.log(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
});
```

docker ls info

```
aee952b16abf   
nats-streaming:0.17.0 
"/nats-streaming-ser…"   
9 minutes ago        
Up 9 minutes        
4222/tcp, 8222/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4223->4223/tcp, :::4223->4223/tcp
```

Comment: What address is your client call trying to connect to?  Can you [edit] your question to include the calling code, and possibly trim out some unnecessary parts of the Compose file (`hostname:`, `networks:`, the three services that aren't involved in the described problem)?

Comment: Client call to nats from the api gateway. Attached code to the question. Nginx route to 8801 where api-gateway listening And then error occures while api-gateway try to connectMicroservice using nats as transport.

Comment: why are you using nats-streaming it's deprecated? is this an old application? you should use `nats` with JetStream enabled for any new development.